# DebuggerDisplay attribute on a DebuggerTypeProxy Class

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, debuggerdisplay

When using [DebuggerDisplay("{OneLineAddress}")] on the debugger proxy'd class, it does not seem to work.  Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or some way around this without adding code to the original class?

```
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(AddressProxy))]
class Address
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }

    public Address(int number, string street, string city, string state, int zip)
    {
        Number = number;
        Street = street;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        Zip = zip;
    }

    [DebuggerDisplay("{OneLineAddress}")] // doesn't seem to work on proxy
    private class AddressProxy
    {
        [DebuggerBrowsableAttribute(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        private Address _internalAddress;

        public AddressProxy(Address internalAddress)
        {
            _internalAddress = internalAddress;
        }

        public string OneLineAddress
        {
            get { return _internalAddress.Number + " " + _internalAddress.Street + " " + _internalAddress.City + " " + _internalAddress.State + " " + _internalAddress.Zip; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DebuggerDisplay attribute should be used on class, not on proxy. To achieve same effect, as you try accomplish, you can just add DebuggerDisplayAttribute on your class (without AddressProxy):

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Number} {Street,nq} {City,nq} {State,nq} {Zip}")]
class Address
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }

    public Address(int number, string street, string city, string state, int zip)
    {
        Number = number;
        Street = street;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        Zip = zip;
    }
}
```

Text `nq` in Street, City and State removes quotes from properties.

Comment: Yeah, but what I really want is to read some property from the Proxy class for the DebuggerDisplay.

Answer (score 0):

The  `[DebuggerDisplay("{OneLineAddress}")]` works only on specific class instance. To see the result in your sample code, you need to create instane of `AddressProxy` class.

To see the "one line address" on the `Address` class you can use

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Number} {Street,nq} {City,nq} {State,nq} {Zip}")]
class Address { .... }
```

Or:

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", Number, Street, City, State, Zip);
}
```

I personally recommend the `ToString()` method, because using in list and arrays this displays the correct state one line address...

The `DebuggerTypeProxy` should be used for list, because it is used in debugger after expanding the current instance. To example see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx